# Spring data mongo pagination

Tags: mongodb, pagination, spring-data

I want to implement pagination with Spring Data Mongo. There are many tutorials and docs suggest to use PagingAndSortingRepository, like this:

```
StoryRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Story, String>{}
```

And so because PagingAndSortingRepository provides api for query with paging, I can use it like:

```
Page<Story> story = storyRepo.findAll(pageable);
```

My question is where actually is this findAll method here implemented? Do I need to write its implementation by myself?
The StoryRepoImpl which implements StoryRepo needs to implement this method?

Comment: How to convert List<User> to Page<User> in spring data mongo pagination ?

Comment: You can get the list by page.getContent()

Answer (score 23):

You do not need to implement the method as when you autowired the Spring object PagingAndSortingRepository, it automatically implements the method for you.

Please note that since you are using Mongodb, you can extend MongoRepository instead.

Then in Spring, enable pagination using this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="INSERT YOUR LINK", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Profile> getAll(int page) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, 5); //get 5 profiles on a page
    Page<Profile> page = repo.findAll(pageable);
    return Lists.newArrayList(page);
```

Comment: deprecated. Use `PageRequest.of()`

Answer (score 11):

I got it working by writing my own implementations, something like this:

```
List<Story> stories = null;

Query query = new Query();
query.with(pageable);

stories = getTemplate().find(query, Story.class);

long total = getTemplate().count(query, Story.class);
Page<Story> storyPage = new PageImpl<Story>(stories, pageable, total);

return storyPage;
```

I'm working with spring data & mongodb, using mongo template to query data.

Comment: it looks like query.with(pageable); not giving correct data sequence wise or pagewise, very strange...

Comment: Problem with this is that doesn't give correct total. You should first find total before applying with(pageable) to query. So, first: long total = getTemplate().count(query, Story.class); And then List<Story> stories = getTemplate().find(query.with(pageable), Story.class);

Answer (score 5):

In Spring Data, you create an interface and add a method using the naming conventions used by Spring data and the framework will generate the implementation of that method.
To implement pagination, i create this method declaration in my repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, ObjectId> {
    Page<Person> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Then, in my service i call this method like this:

```
Page<Person> persons = personRepository.findByName("Alex", PageRequest.of(0, 100));
```

Here, the page will contain 100 element.

Answer (score 2):

To paginate a query, you can use something like below:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    Page<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

For more details, please refer to the second query in Example 6.6 in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

The method is implemented by a store-specific class. For the Spring Data JPA module, it's [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.4.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java). You usually let a DI container create instances for these repository interfaces. With Spring you'd activate Spring Data repositories by either using `@EnableJpaRepository` on a JavaConfig class or

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />
```

This will create a proxy instance for the repo, so that you can get it injected into your clients:

```
class MyClient {

  @Inject
  public MyClient(PersonRepository repository) {
    …
  }
}
```

Comment: How to get the LastRecord from mongo using Spring Repository or Query?

Comment: Please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query1 = new Query();
Integer startIndex = page * size;
Integer endIndex = (page * size) + size;

List<dto> totalRecord = mongoOperation.find(query1, dto.class);

query1.limit((endIndex > totalRecord.size() ? totalRecord.size() : endIndex));

List<dto> responseList = mongoOperation.find(query1, dto.class);

int end = (endIndex > (totalRecord.size() - 1) ? totalRecord.size() - 1 : endIndex);
if (totalRecord.size() > 0 && end == 0)
  end = 1;

if (totalRecord.size() > 0)
  responseList = responseList.subList(startIndex, end);

int totalPages = totalRecord.size() / size + (totalRecord.size() % size == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answer says: you don't need to implement the repository interface classes. The generating magic will handle it.

I wrote this answer because of say implementation way of PageRequest deprecated
-the `Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(fromIndex, toIndex);` one.

If you want to implement a pageable request nowadays, you need to use like following:

```
PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(pageNum, pageSize);

List<MyEntity> result =myEntityRepository.findAll(page).toList();
```