# Sliced result using mongo template for the document(not nested)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-mongodb

How to retrieve Page result using mongo template

I have a scenario like below :

```
    final Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(offset, limit);
    Criteria criteria = where("");
    if (null != type) {
        criteria = criteria.and("type").is(type);
    }
    if (null != revision) {
        criteria = criteria.and("current_revision_data.data.revision_start").is(revision);
    }
    Query query = query(criteria).with(pageableRequest);
    Page<Invoice> invoices = mongoTemplate.find(query, Invoice.class);
```

Could someone point me how to get page of the result?

EDIT : To be more specific the last line that is :
Page invoices = mongoTemplate.find(query, Invoice.class);
is a compilation failure.

I would like to get Paged results which I could not find using MongoTemplate

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you meant by slice here? can you explain with an example.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html

There is something called Slice just like Page, if you are not familiar with Slice then you can as well think of it as a Page

Comment: i have edited my sample code to use Page, because i think not many will be familiar with Slice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data mongo pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366666/spring-data-mongo-pagination)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. This one is for the entire document as such the other one is for slicing the nested array

Comment: For now as a workaorund this is what I am doing is :

    final Pageable pageableRequest = PageRequest.of(offset, limit);
    Criteria criteria .................
    Query query = query(criteria).limit(limit+1).offset(offset);
    List<Invoice> invoices = mongoTemplate.find(query, Invoice.class);        
        boolean hasNext = false;
        if(invoices.size() == (limit + 1)) {
            invoices.remove(invoices.get(limit));
            hasNext = true;
        }
    Slice<Invoice> invoices = new SliceImpl<>(invoices, PageRequest.of(offset/limit, limit), hasNext);

Comment: I found this answer working, but with changes from my comment below the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417838/4082981