# Using spring how do we return paginated list of objects from an Object

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, spring-mongodb

I am accepting a paginated response from service and performing an operation on it. which results in to a singular object. 
object which contains aggregation queryResult from mongo, 
How to return paginated response of objects within a single object from endpoint.

```
{
"fullName:"abc",

"educationData":[

// paginated response from another service.
//queryResult

],

"cellNo" : "12345",
"address" : "pqr";
}
```

I want to paginate list of "educationData", 
but I ended up paginating entire object.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366666/spring-data-mongo-pagination

Comment: Well, I went through the possible duplicate @MebinJoe, the problems are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already receiving a paginated response from a service, you can carry forward the same response.
Create a class which implements PageImpl which will give you all the pagination information for eg:-

```
public class CustomPageImpl extends PageImpl<T> {

  @JsonCreator
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public CustomPageImpl(@JsonProperty("content") List<T> content,
      @JsonProperty("number") int page,
      @JsonProperty("size") int size,
      @JsonProperty("totalElements") long totalElements) {
    super(content, new PageRequest(page, size), totalElements);
  }
}
```

change your response object and append these fields from CustomPageImpl class.

```
{
"fullName:"abc",

"educationData":[

// paginated response from another service.
//queryResult

],

"cellNo" : "12345",
"address" : "pqr",
"totalElements": 0,
"totalPages": 0
}
```